# clean clearcase. pure uninstall etc. after faile to load views in cc explorer

Tags: clearcase

i have views which works grate from CLI but cc-explorer fails to load, therefore i have no easy way to do basic actions.
any ideas?

I removed it completely but some thing was left behined so uninstall and reinstall did not help

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can load your snapshot view from the CLI ([`cleartool update`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm)), then you can launch the ClearCase Explorer directly from said loaded snapshot view:

```
cd /root/of/your/snapshot/view
clearexplorer .
```

That way, even if the ClearCase Explorer doesn't load them, it can at least displayed they loaded content.

Comment: thanks,
I did it but it stacked while loading.
* i am looking for an answer here because support can take very long

Comment: What does "stacked" means? Froze? Stalled? Do you have an error message? Are you sure your view is fully loaded through the CLI? What ClearCase version are you using?

Comment: I can view files, checkout, edit etc from CLI. but when opening CC this way it "keep thinking" (mouse cursor keeps rolling) and never get to show the view (all parts remains blank).

Comment: @ozma do you open the ClearCase Explorer like I mention in the answer?

Comment: I opened it from "right-click" context menu on the view folder. I will try CLI and update. thanks

Comment: I tried it from CLI "cleartool update" and i get the following error "cleartool: Error: '.........' is not a valid snapshot view path." . the view was created on another machine (linux) and I am accessing it from windows network drive. P.S: it is a dynamic view.